# Error inflating class fragment for a news app with multiple fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-mvvm

I have been having issues with launching the application. It builds fine but as soon as it launches it ends the error: "Error inflating class fragment comes up" The activity class has the section that deals with the bottom navigation and the initializing of the view model
xml package for main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.NewsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/newsNavHostFragment"
    android:name ="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost = "true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/news_nav_graph"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main activity class

```
package com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.Database.ArticleDatabase
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.R
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.data.NewsRepository
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.viewmodel.NewsViewModel
import com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.viewmodel.NewsViewModelProviderFactory
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_news.*

class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var  viewModel: NewsViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        val newsRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newsRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
       bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())
    }
```

Error message.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp/com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.NewsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Binary XML file line #28 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Binary XML file line #28 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28 in com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp:layout/activity_news: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModel has not been initialized
        at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.NewsActivity.getViewModel(NewsActivity.kt:17)
        at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.fragments.BreakNewsFragment.onViewCreated(BreakNewsFragment.kt:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
2021-08-21 11:46:55.108 27547-27547/com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp.ui.NewsActivity.onCreate(NewsActivity.kt:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You should not be using the `<fragment>` tag at all, ever, and you should see a warning to replace it with `FragmentContainerView` in your XML.

Comment: @ianhanniballake 
In case if parent view before `FragmentContainerView` is not `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` it will fail at runtime. I would like to add to your comments.